# Detect which tab is selected with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, materialize

I am using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) to create tabs. So I am at point where I want to detect which tab is opened and then configure the UI using Javascript or Jquery.

E.g

```
 if (tab.index == 0 || 'brands'){
   //Configure some UI
}else if(tab.index == 1 || 'products'){
  //Configure some UI
}
```

The HTML part looks like this:

```
<ul class="tabs blue-grey darken-2">
    <li class="tab col s6"><a class="active" href="#brands" style="color: white;">Brands</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s6"><a style="color: white;" href="#products">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

I already did manually change tab on button click like this:

```
$('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'products');
```

but do not know how to achieve the question part. I hope to get some help :) I went through many similar questions but didn't find solution. If the question is somehow dublicate please comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `onShow` callback. See http://materializecss.com/tabs.html

This code is untested and there is no simple example of how to use onShow at the vendor website but I hope it will show you the way. 'some_param' is where you need to know the attributes of the tab object - maybe it has an index. If not then maybe you could add differentiating classes to the first and other tabs and use jquery .hasClass(classname') to decide what happens next.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id').onShow(function(selectedTab){

    if (selectedTab.some_param === some_val){
        ...do something
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Hasn't had luck. As I understand the onShow should know that after this tab is opened then do something. But I tried for example `window.alert("Clicked tab opened");` but it didn't do anything. Also I couldn't find the parameters. I went through their .js, the only thing I saw was var index = 0. So I assume the index is starting from 0.